# How to change <span> color on hover

Tags: html, css, colors

I've got div for social platforms in my css. I want to change colors for each platform on hover. They are in `<span>`. How to reach it in `CSS`? This is the `HTML`:

```
<div class="content">


<ul class="social-media-links--platforms platforms inline horizontal">
      <li>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/u" target="_blank">
        <span class="fa fa-facebook fa-4x"></span>
      </a>

          </li>
      <li>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/u" target="_blank">
        <span class="fa fa-instagram fa-4x"></span>
      </a>

          </li>
      <li>
      <a href="https://www.twitter.com/u" target="_blank">
        <span class="fa fa-twitter fa-4x"></span>
      </a>

          </li>
  </ul>

    </div>
```

This is how I changed all social links:

```
.social-media-links--platforms a{  
    color: #fffff0;
}
```

Now I want to add each of them different color on hover. This doesn't work:

```
.fa.fa-instagram.fa-4x a:hover{
    color: black;
}
```

**@EDIT**

It's almost ok but when I move the mouse out of the icon It becomes the standard link color for a sec:  not hover (white) -> hover(color of the media) - > not hover (standard link color for a sec) - > white again

Comment: Change the order: `a:hover .fa.fa-instagram {`... As the `span` tag is inside of the `a` tag...

Comment: `.social-media-links--platforms a:hover .fa-facebook { color: blue; }`

Answer (score 2):

Your fa-class is in your a-element. Try this:

```
a:hover .fa.fa-instagram.fa-4x {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: That's nice but when I move mouse out of the icon it change for a sec to the standard link color